# Create new tables by looping through another table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin as the GUI to create my database structures. I have a table of courses with 1500 rows. I want to loop through the course table and create 1500 tables based on each row of the course table where the name of the new tables will be equal to the course_id column of the course table. This is my attempt so far but I know there is a problem with the use of row and a variable. Any advice to solve for the outcome I need is very much appreciated.

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE myTable()

BEGIN 

DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE tableCalled varchar(50);
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses INTO n;
    SET i=0;

WHILE i<n DO 
  SELECT course_id Row i FROM courses INTO tableCalled;

  CREATE TABLE tableCalled ('id' UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'unit' varchar(20),
    'description' varchar(100),'other' varchar(100),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
       ENGINE = InnoDB;

  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

END 
$

CALL myTable();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query to create a script which can be ran to create the tables.  I am assuming that course_id is a string that is a valid table name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `', courses.course_id, 
        '` (''id'' UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,''unit'' varchar(20),
        ''description'' varchar(100),''other'' varchar(100),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
      ENGINE = InnoDB;') AS statements
FROM courses;
```

You should end up with results like the following, which you can copy/paste and execute to create your tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `math101` ('id' UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'unit' varchar(20),
    'description' varchar(100),'other' varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE `science102` ('id' UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'unit' varchar(20),
    'description' varchar(100),'other' varchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
...
```